# SQL Server 2019 instance seems to randomly dump its query plan cache

Tags: sql-server

The instance in question has maximum server memory set to 6GB, but only seems to be using half a GB. I checked the query plan cache by using the query on this page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

```
SELECT usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, text   
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans   
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)   
WHERE usecounts > 1   
ORDER BY usecounts DESC;  
GO
```

After running that, I only see about 3 plans. When I run the application that uses this database, sometimes there will be 300-400 plans, but about 30 seconds later the same query will only show about 3 plans in the cache.

I've run SQL profiler and can't find anything running a `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

There are 3 other instances on this server that are consuming their allocated memory just fine. One in particular is allowed to eat 2GB and has consumed the entire amount with over 500 plans consistently in its cache.

Other than a scheduled task running `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` every 30-60 seconds, is there anything that would cause SQL Server 2019 to behave in this way?

Comment: Yes, if there is memory pressure from the rest of the system. Considering you have four(!) instances on one machine, have you set the `Max Server Memory` correctly on each one?

Comment: I believe so. The system has 32 GB of memory. Our 4 instances are allowed maximums of 2, 6, 6 and 12 for a total of 26 GB allocated to SQL instances.

Comment: If you run a query that requires the maximum amount of memory (for sorts/hashes etc) then query plans will be evicted to make room

Comment: You could check the error log for anything interesting -- an explicit plan cache flush will be recorded there as well, as should memory pressure (if the server thinks it's experiencing some). The [`optimize for ad hoc workloads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/optimize-for-ad-hoc-workloads-server-configuration-option) option is also worth considering, as it typically has little to no negative impact on performance while potentially saving a lot of memory.

Comment: another question is : does this server (I mean the machine) is a VM ? If yes, does the MEMORY has been fixed or is it floating ? I yes, this is a complementary point of the @Charlieface remark

Comment: Yes, it is a VM. I will see if I can figure out if memory is fixed or floating. It's on VMWare. I would assume it is fixed since only one instance seems to ever be affected by this issue.

Comment: @JeroenMostert there are a few messages in the event viewer mentioning a cachestore flush of 'Object Plans', 'SQL Plans', and 'Bound Trees' cachestores, but that was after I increased max memory by 1MB on a whim wondering if that would do anything. The instance still continues to cache query plans for about 30-60 seconds, then flush them. There are no messages for these random flushes that I can see.

Comment: Any chance there is a configuration option somewhere that specifies how long cached query plans are allowed to live?

Comment: No, plans live and accumulate for as long as there is memory for them (and no event occurs that necessitates removal). There is no time-based expiration. You may consider setting up an XEvent trace that includes the `sp_cache_remove` and `query_cache_removal_statistics` event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple facets of SQL Server will 'compete' for buffer cache, including:

- Data
- Plans
- Clerks (i.e., other caches)
- **Memory Grants**
- etc

The amount of space that Plans can consume is dictated by thresholds defined here:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/cc293624(v=technet.10)
- https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/sql-server-plan-cache-limits/

And, once plans start to exceed those thresholds, the SQLOS will beging to 'eagerly cleanup/clip/evict' less frequently used plans.

Likewise, if OTHER clerks (caches for things like schemas, objects, and permissions-caches against those objects - i.e., TOKENPERMS) exceed certain, internal, cache thresholds they TOO can cause the SQLOS to start scavenging ALL caches - including cache plans.

For example:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/query-performance-issues-associated-with-a-large-sized-security-cache

Likewise, Memory Grants can/will use buffer cache during query processing. For example, if you're querying a huge table and the engine expects to get back (or hang-on-to for further processing) roughly 1KB of for each of 10 million rows, you're going to need potentially 9GB of buffer space for said query to process. (Or, there are mechanics LIKE this in play with memory grants - the example I've cited is WAY too simplistic - to the point of not being even close to accurate).
The point being, however, that these grants can/will be given RAM directly from the overall buffer cache and can/will cause INTERNAL memory pressure against the plan-cache (and all other caches for that matter).
In short, memory grants can be a huge problem with SOME workloads.

Otherwise, external factors (other apps - especially memory-hungry apps) can/will cause the OS to tell SQL Server to 'cough up' memory it has been using. (You can prevent this by granting the Lock_Pages_In_Memory User Right to the SQL Server service account - just be sure you know what you're doing here.)

In your case, with 4x distinct instances running, I'd assume you're likely running into 'external' memory pressure against the instance in question.

That said, you can query `sys.dm_os_ring_buffers` to get insight into whether or not memory pressure is happening - as per posts like the following:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-what-are-the-ring_buffer_resource_monitor-telling-me
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mvpawardprogram/using-sys-dm_os_ring_buffers-to-diagnose-memory-issues-in-sql-server
- https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/identifying-external-memory-pressure-with-dm_os_ring_buffers-and-ring_buffer_resource_monitor/

Along those lines, I use the following query/diagnostic to check for memory pressure:

```
WITH core AS ( 
    SELECT 
        EventTime,
        record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/Notification)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as [Type],
        record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsProcess)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsProcess],
        record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsSystem)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsSystem],
        record.value('(/Record/ResourceMonitor/IndicatorsPool)[1]', 'int') as [IndicatorsPool], 
        record.value('(/Record/MemoryNode/@id)[1]', 'int') as [MemoryNode],
        record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailablePhysicalMemory)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Avail Phys Mem, Kb],
        record.value('(/Record/MemoryRecord/AvailableVirtualAddressSpace)[1]', 'bigint') AS [Avail VAS, Kb], 
        record
    FROM (
        SELECT
            DATEADD (ss, (-1 * ((cpu_ticks / CONVERT (float, ( cpu_ticks / ms_ticks ))) - [timestamp])/1000), GETDATE()) AS EventTime,
            CONVERT (xml, record) AS record
        FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers
        CROSS JOIN sys.dm_os_sys_info
        WHERE ring_buffer_type = 'RING_BUFFER_RESOURCE_MONITOR') AS tab
)

SELECT 
    EventTime,
    [Type],
    IndicatorsProcess,
    IndicatorsSystem,
    IndicatorsPool,
    MemoryNode,
    CAST([Avail Phys Mem, Kb] / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS decimal(20,2)) [Avail Phys Mem (GB)],
    CAST([Avail VAS, Kb] / (1024.0 * 1024.0) AS decimal(20,2)) [Avail VAS (GB)]
    ,record
FROM 
    core
WHERE 
    [Type] = N'RESOURCE_MEMPHYSICAL_LOW'
ORDER BY 
    EventTime DESC;
```

As in, if you run that against effectively ANY SQL Server instance, you REALLY don't want to see ANY results from this query. Or, if you do, they should be at times when you're running REALLY heavy workloads (ugly data-loading/population jobs or other huge processing operations) that you're already aware are issues/problems from a performance perspective.

Otherwise, the occasional entry/hiccup (i.e., set of results) isn't necessarily a reason to worry about major problems, but if you're routinely seeing entries/rows/results from the above with regular workloads, you'll want to investigate things like all of the details listed above (cache and clerk sizes/thresholds, trap for any large memory grants, check plan-cache sizing based on overall RAM, etc.) AND/OR start looking into cache clock hands to see exactly where memory is being scavenged:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/slavao/q-and-a-clock-hands-what-are-they-for

Comment: Yes, there seemed to be some external memory pressure in our case. There was a sync service on this machine that had started to eat quite a bit more memory than usual and was causing the problem instance to give up its query cache. This is a great diagnostic query--thanks for sharing! We will be making some adjustments to our infrastructure.